# Cannot access symlinked file in shared hosting in Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, web-hosting, symlink

I use hostinger and I have two folders in my parent hosting directory

1. my-laravel-app-folder
2. public_html

**in *public/index.php I changed***

1. `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` **to** `require __DIR__.'/../my-laravel-app-folder/vendor/autoload.php';`
2. `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` **to** `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../my-laravel-app-folder/bootstrap/app.php';`

**in public/.htaccess file I changed**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

From parent / directory ,I have already run

```
ln -s my-laravel-app-folder/storage/app/public public_html/storage
```

But I still cannot access to linked storage files and got **`404`** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, it's when creating a symlink ,I have to include absolute path for folders instead of current path .For example,

- For `my-laravel-app-folder/storage/app/public` replaced with `/home/u440262284/domains/mysite.com/my-laravel-app-folder/storage/app/public`
  instead and
- For also `public_html/storage` replaced with `/home/u440262284/domains/mysite.com/public_html/storage`

It worked !!!

Answer (score 2):

do symlink

```
ln -s my-laravel-app-folder/storage/app/public public_html/storage
```

**Remove** the **index.php** and **.htaccess** file from **public_html/storage** and **copy manually** from **your laravel project** to **public_html/storage**.
You **don't need to change** your **index.php** file, try to change your domain path into **public_html/storage/public**

Comment: Sorry but It didn't worked for me if I didn't specify absolute path while creating symlinks.